# Where do I download Vine Linux for PowerPC?

Tags: linux, powerpc, download

Where do I download the latest version of Vine Linux for PowerPC? I cannot find the link for PowerPC download on their website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from the (English) [`RELEASE-NOTES` of release 6.0](http://ftp.vinelinux.org/pub/Vine/Vine-6.0/x86_64/RELEASE-NOTES) and [5.2 (ppc)](http://ftp.vinelinux.org/pub/Vine/Vine-5.2/ppc/RELEASE-NOTES), **there is no PPC support for 6.0**.